# Replace \ with space in a file

Tags: awk, gsub

In a file, I have to replace the special characters `\/:?|°%` with space. I tried the code below, but it is not replacing `\` with space:

```
awk '{gsub(/[\/:?|°%]/," "); print} else print}' $file
```

Comment: You have to escape the backslash with another backslash - and the `else print` doesn't make any sense here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk '{gsub(/[/:?|°%\\]/," ");print}' file
```

Answer (score 0):

What about using `tr` for this?

```
tr '\\/:?|º%' ' ' < file
```

Note `\` needs to be escaped to prevent it from having an special meaning.

For example:

```
$ tr '\\/:?\|º%' ' ' <<< "hello\i am/here:oh?wait|iºam%done"
hello i am here oh wait i  am done
```